# How to query on Embedded document within an array - MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've trying to query on an embedded document i've created that has the following model: a user has a facebook account and a business (emprendimiento). The 'emprendimiento' has categorias_asociadas, that is an empty array that will receive its value(s) from a form tag (Buy, Sell or Invest).

I would like to query all Users that have an emprendimiento that have a catogorias_asociadas that is either buy, sell or invest.**

I'm looking for something like this:

```
Users.find({'emprendimiento.categorias_asociadas': {$all: 'Buy'}})

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    facebook: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        name: String,
        photo: String
    },
    emprendimiento: { 
        nombre:String,
        slogan:String,  
        logo:String,
        web:String,
        categorias_asociadas: [],
        about: String,
        quevende: String,
        ubicacion: String,
        descripcion: String
    }
});
```

I've accomplished something similar before when I had the 'emprendimiento' in another model:

```
var emprendimientoSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    nombre:String,
    slogan:String,
    logo:String,
    categorias_asociadas: []
    });

var Emprendimiento = mongoose.model('Emprendimiento', emprendimientoSchema)
```

By doing this query I was able to filter all emprendimiento that have compraVenta (Buy) in its categorias_asociadas.

```
Emprendimiento.find({categorias_asociadas:{$all:["buy"]}}, function (err, compraventa) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        else {
do something here 
          }
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did something like `Users.find({'emprendimiento.categorias_asociadas': {$all: ['Buy']}})` not work for you ? Is `emprendimiento` an embedded  array ?

Comment: Hey thanks using the [ ] between 'Buy' did the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked well :)

```
 Users.find({'emprendimiento.categorias_asociadas': {$all: ['Buy']}})
```